# How to make a PyTorch Distribution on GPU

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch, distribution

Is it possible to make the PyTorch distributions create their samples directly on GPU.

If I do

```
from torch.distributions import Uniform, Normal
normal = Normal(3, 1)
sample = normal.sample()
```

Then sample will be on CPU. Of course it is possible to do `sample = sample.to(torch.device("cuda"))` to make it on GPU. But is there a way to have the sample go directly to GPU without first creating it on CPU?

PyTorch distributions inherit from `Object`, not `nn.Module` so it does not have a `to` method the put the distribution instance on GPU.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Distributions use the reparametrization trick. Thus giving size 0 tensors which are on GPU to the distribution constructor works. As follows:

```
normal = Normal(torch.tensor(0).to(device=torch.device("cuda")), torch.tensor(1).to(device=torch.device("cuda")))
```

Comment: this blows with error `normal_cuda_kernel not implemented for long` in normal distribution. the correct code (note 0 and 1 are 0.0 and 1.0 now): `normal = Normal(torch.tensor(0.0).to(device=device, torch.tensor(1.0).to(device=device))`

Comment: Really wish there were more succint notation for this

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using a Normal Distribution as my prior in a neural net model. I have a class called class1, for example, and in the init function I have to initiate my prior. However, calling `.to('cuda')` of an instance of class1 doesn't change the distribution device and causes error in later usages. Therefore, I could have used register buffers to manage it as follows.

```
class class1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.register_buffer("mean", torch.tensor(0.))
        self.register_buffer("var", torch.tensor(1.))
    def get_dist(self):
        return torch.distributions.Normal(self.mean, self.var)
```

However, I have several priors, and it's not possible to register_buffer a list. So, an option could be initiating distributions in get_dist property unless you don't care about the time complexity of initiating distributions. I decided to define a function for initiating distributions and a try-except in get_dist to handle different states. If the distributions variable is not assigned or on CPU while we expect it to be on GPU, it jumps to except where I initiate the distributions using `torch.zeros(..).to(device)`.

Overall, to handle this error of CPU/GPU device, you need to initiate a distribution using Tensor input parameters with appropriate device. And the main reason is `torch.Distribution` module hasn't a device attribute unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same problem, and thanks to the other answers here for the pointers. I want to offer another option if you want a distribution inside a module, which is to override the `to` method in the module and manually call the `to` methods on the distribution parameter tensors. I've only tested with `Uniform` but works well here.

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.rng = Uniform(
            low=torch.zeros(3),
            high=torch.ones(3)
        )
    
    def to(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().to(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rng.low = self.rng.low.to(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rng.high = self.rng.high.to(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can put your model on the gpu as usual and `self.rng.sample()` will return a sample on the correct device.

Comment: Note that you have to include more parameters depending on the distribution.
E.g. for `torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal` you need to set: `_unbroadcasted_scale_tril`, `loc`,
`scale_tril`,
`covariance_matrix`, and
`precision_matrix` and explicitely have to check if they are `None` for the last three.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem of "transferring non-parameter/buffer attributes to GPU" by overriding `self._apply(self, fn)` method of your network. Like this:

```
def _apply(self, fn):
    # apply fn() to your modules
    for module in self.children():  # like 'ResNet_backbone'
        module._apply(fn)
    # apply fn() to your prior
    self.prior.attr1 = fn(self.prior.attr1)  # like 'MultivariateNormal.loc', need to be Tensor
    self.prior.attr2 = fn(self.prior.attr2) 
    ···
    self.prior.attrN = fn(self.prior.attrN) 
    # if we do not use register_buffer(Tensor)
    #    apply fn() to your non-parameter/buffer attributes
    #    need to be Tensor too
    self.attr1 = fn(self.attr1)
    self.attr2 = fn(self.attr2) 
    ···
    self.attrN = fn(self.attrN)
```